# Rack port to Java?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, port, rack

Do you know if [Rack](http://rack.rubyforge.org/) was ported to Java? To be more specific, I am aware of [jruby-rack](http://jruby-rack.appspot.com/) but I am looking for a native Java (re)implementation of Rack, if any?!

Thank you in advance,
- florin

Comment: Umm... `JavaEE`? `javax.servlet`?

Comment: @skaffman Umm.. I kind of know what the Servlet is, see: JPublish ;) but I was asking if Rack was ported to Java. Ty anyway.

Comment: But what would be the point, when the Servlet API seems to provide the same thing?

Comment: @skaffman: Does it really provide the same thing? For example, here is a simply "echo" style Rack application: you `POST` some data to it and it simply returns back the data you posted: `run -> env { [200, {'Content-Type' => 'text/plain'}, [env['rack.input'].read]] }` Is that also 1 line with servlets? Oh, and yes: this *is* the *complete* code for the entire application. There is nothing else needed. No configuration file. No XML. Not even a webserver is needed. Rack will automatically find an appropriate webserver for you.

Comment: Thank you, Jörg! These are exactly the reasons I am looking for Rack. I am using it for all my Rails projects and I wanted to know if there is a java version available. I'll have a look at JRack because I am want to use it for a new Java open source project. Thanks again for your comments!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came across JRack at some point, though I don't really know anything about it.

Here's a blog post about JRack: http://blog.approvaltests.com/2009/09/hello-jrack.html

Download link: http://sourceforge.net/projects/approvaltests/files/

Looks like it's been at version 0.0.001  since September 09, so use at your own risk.

Comment: JRack is something I could start with. Thank you for your answer, Jon.

Comment: I forked the project and I am starting to clean it up. Here's the [GIT repo](https://github.com/florinpatrascu/jrack), in case anyone is interested. Cheers.